# Is there any way to print directly from my iPad to my wifi-connected printer?

Tags: ipad, printing, wifi

I am happy to purchase an app, but the only printing app I'm aware of seems to just let your ipad connect to a computer that is connected to the printer and effectively print through it.

I'm looking to print from my ipad without the use of another computer.   Both the ipad and the printer are on the same wifi network (which is how I print from our laptops).

EDIT:  In my specific case, the printer is a Canon MP990.

Comment: Which brand is the printer ?

Comment: Looks like the November release of iOS4.2 for the iPad will feature built-in printing, too. Not sure how widespread it will be throughout the system, though - I'm guessing it will be an API thing that app developers will need to 'add' to their programs.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 4.3 now offer [AirPrint](http://www.apple.com/ipad/features/airprint.html).

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to print pictures and
>   photos, you can use [Epson iPrint](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/epson-iprint/id326876192?mt=8)
>   (there are similar apps from other
>   printer manufacturers, e.g. [Canon
>   iEPP](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/iepp_home), [HP iPrint Photo 2.0](http://itunes.apple.com/app/hp-iprint-photo-2-0/id299531647?mt=8),
>   [Kodak Pic Flick](http://www.kodak.com/eknec/PageQuerier.jhtml?pq-path=15727&CID=go&idhbx=picflick) or [Lexmark
>   LexPrint](http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=en&userlocale=EN_US&productCode=LEXPRINT&page=recommendedDownloads&segment=DOWNLOAD)). For printing PDFs or
>   other documents, the already mentioned
>   "[print n share](http://appshopper.com/productivity/print-share-printing-for-emails-files-contacts-web-pages-photos-and-more)", "Print Bureau"
>   (both from [eurosmartz](http://www.eurosmartz.com/)) or Air
>   Sharing Pro from Avatron could be
>   useful.

Via [piquadrat](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/users/702/piquadrat) answering my [similar questio](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/questions/1095/can-any-apps-print-from-the-iphone)n on [gadgets.stackexchange.com](http://gadgets.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Canon made a utility for their printers called [Easy-PhotoPrint](http://itunes.apple.com/app/canon-easy-photoprint-for/id331269951).

Otherwise, they are more generic utility like [ePrint](http://www.e-workshop-dev.com/PC_EN/eprint_e.html) (but it's far more perfect or convenient).

Answer (score 1):

I have used the iPad part of [PrintCentral](http://mobile.eurosmartz.com/products/printcentral.html) with mixed results - I have a HP Color LaserJet 2605dn connected to an Apple Airport router. The printer is configured as 'A4' (I'm in the UK) and while some things print just fine from the iPad, other things seem to have pagination issues. Printing from emails and Safari generally seems okay.

To be fair I think that the only way you're going to get this to work seamlessly is if you can find a wifi printer with drivers for the iPad (do they even exist) - everything else is likely to be some kind of compromise.

EDIT: Just to be clear, PrintCentral can either print directly to the 'network' printer, or can send data to an app on your Mac/PC. I haven't tried the latter approach (and your question says you don't want to do it that way anyway) - but I have used it to connect and directly print to my HP from the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Google Cloud Print? https://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/apps.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what kind of printer you have.

The fundamental problem is printer drivers. That is why all of the apps use a server/proxy on a desktop computer, that way the can piggyback the desktops existing printer drivers. Otherwise they would need to include drivers for all supported printers.

A few of the printer vendors have iPhone/iPad apps that can take to their network printers, but obviously those only support their printers (an usually only recent ones).

I expect this to change at some point in the future (when Apple builds printing support into iOS), but this how things stand with iOS 3.2/4.0.